# Why is variable not printing correctly?

Tags: java, class

Why did the following program output `Method B 0` instead of `Method B 200`? I can't understand what my problem is.

```
class A{
    int a=100;
    void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("myMethod of A : "+a);
    }
    A(){
        myMethod();//calling my method
    }
}
class B extends A{
    int a=200;
    void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("myMethod of B : "+a);
    }
 }
 class Demo{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new B();
     }
 }
```

Comment: When you create a B object it extends A which has a constructor that runs myMethod. This causes the myMethod code on B to be run immediately before `a` has been set to 200. You can avoid this by renaming myMethod on B to something else.
It would be useful for you to run through this in debug mode with all possible breakpoints and a watch on `a` so that you can see where the code jumps to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instance field initializers run *after* the superclass constructor has been called. So the order of execution is:

- Call to `new B()`
- Start to initialize instance of `B`:
- Implicitly call `super()`

  - Start to initialize the instance with respect to `A`
  - Initialize field `A.a` as 100
  - Call `myMethod`, which is overridden in `B`
  - Print out `B.a` which is 0
  - `A` constructor returns
- Initialize field `B.a` as 200
- Execute the body of the `B` constructor, which is empty

As you can see, your `println` call occurs when the `B.a` field hasn't been initialized yet.

This is why executing methods which have been overridden (in your case `myMethod()`) from a constructor is so dangerous - it can end up working with state which hasn't gone through its normal initialization yet.

Answer (score 0):

when you do **new B()** then the default constructor of class A will be called. The constructor of class A calls myMethod() function of class B. 
At this moment the value of **a** in class B won't be 200 (it will be 0) because it is being called by the constructor of class A.

To get what you want, you should define your default constructor in class B and call the myMethod as.

```
 B(){
        myMethod();
    }
```